# How to get divs and anchors stacked on top of each other with the same width

Tags: css, html

For my website that I am making, I have this code:

```
.menu{      
}

.menu a{
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color: #d7d7d7;
    font: bold 16px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #444;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.menu a:hover{
    border: double 6px #00F;
    color: #00F;
    background-color: #FFF;
    font: bold 20px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: center;
}

.sidebar{
    width:220px;
    margin-top:8px;
    margin-left:3px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:10px;
    clear:left;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #888;
}

.sidebar p{
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <b style="color:#666;">Menu</b>
    <div class="menu">
        <p><a href="#">Profile</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Friends</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Community Service</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Messages</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason the only way I can position the anchors on top of each other like this is by putting them in paragraph tags, but I don't want that.  Here is a picture of how all that code looks:

[image: Code Overview]

I want the menu to look like the Log In and Create an Account button, but there is no difference between the CSS, the only thing that could be differentiated between them is that the div containing them is positioned in a table.  So I was wondering how I could achieve that same-width-and-height-as-the-ones-above-and-bellow-it kind of div.  Also I tried putting it into a table and that only squashed it together and took out the round edges (CSS display: table in the .menu and display: table-cell in the anchor also does not work because it squashes it).  Here is the rest of my code: http://pastebin.com/ZLS94ZvQ thanks for your help!

Comment: You should be able to set `display:block;` and `width: blahpx;` in your css and just adjust the left and right `padding` of the container. Ofcourse it would be much easier for me to diagnose if you posted your url.

Comment: @tech0925 well its not hosted yet, and I'll try the display and width right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your HTML in:

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <b style="color:#666;">Menu</b>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Community Service</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and your CSS in:

```
.menu{      
  list-style:none; /* remove style from <ul> but leave a 40px margin on the left */
  margin-left:-40px; /* this remove the 40px margin on the left */
}
.menu li{
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0; /* this adds 10px top and bottom of each <LI> element */
}
.menu a{
    display: block;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color:  #d7d7d7; 
    font: bold 16px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #444;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.menu a:hover{
    border: double 6px #00F;
    color: #00F;
    background-color:  #FFF; 
    font: bold 20px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: center;
}

.sidebar{
    width:220px;
    margin-top:8px;
    margin-left:3px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:10px;
    clear:left;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #888;
}
```

Using `<ul>` is better and semantically correct. For search engines it should be even better to wrap the `<ul>` with `<nav>`

Comment: It worked great, but now I cannot figure out how to make the list items closer together, I tried editing the padding for the list items and taking out the padding in the anchors but that didn't work.

Comment: You mean less space between the lines, right? Just edit `margin: 10px 0` in `.menu li`. The first value (`10px`) is the margin-top/-bottom (10px for `margin-top` and 10px for `margin-bottom`).

Comment: another question: is there a way to avoid using the `margin-left:-40px;` inside of the `.menu` class? or does it not matter?

Comment: Setting the `list-style` to `none` removes the dots from each item, but not the space occupied. That `margin-left` remove this white space. If you remove that property, your menu will be shifted by 40px on the right.

Comment: ah so its always a 40px difference? thats good to know, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using

```
<ul>
<li>Your link here</li>
<li>Your link here</li>
<li>Your link here</li>
<li>Your link here</li>
</ul>
```

to list your links. That is the most common way of doing it.

Then you can simply set your `li` tags to `display: block;` and set a `width` to stretch out the links so they are all even.